# WebJob throws FunctionIndexingException with multiple methods

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

These methods work individually, but do not work together.

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue1")] JobClass message,
        TextWriter log)
    {
    }

    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue2")] JobClass[] message,
        TextWriter log)
    {
    }
}
```

On run of the WebJob throws:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException
>   occurred Message: Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException' in
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll Additional information: Error
>   indexing method 'ProcessQueueMessage'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebJob cannot setup multiple methods that share a name (overloads). Rename the methods so that they are not overloads:

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue1")] JobClass message,
        TextWriter log)
    {
    }

    public static void ProcessQueueMessages([QueueTrigger("queue2")] JobClass[] messages,
        TextWriter log)
    {
    }
}
```